# object with ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback

Tags: android, kotlin, itemtouchhelper

So I was reading the documentation of ItemTouchHelper and tried to make one.

```
val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT){
    //Should let me override functions
    })
```

But in the simpleCallBack tells me that it ***cannot create an instance of the abstract class*** which makes absolute sense.
Then I didn't know how to solve this. So I've decided to go to a project that I've made following a tutorial to understand it and this is what I found

```
val itemTouchHelper = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT){
    //override both functions
    }
```

From what i get in this line is that object of type ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback pass to the variable. But pretty sure this doesn't answer my doubt, need to know what is exactly going there.

I know it's a newbie doubt that everyone should know, but I don't know it yet!

**Question:** So, exactly what's going on the **object :** ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(..){} and is that a good way to solve it or is there any better?

Comment: `So, exactly what's going on the object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(..){}`
A new anonymous class is being instantiated. And yes currently this is the best approach because there is no synthetic sugar for this (as of now).

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Thank you very much for solving my doubt. I totally forgot that was the way to make an anonymous class in Kotlin!! haha